# How to calculate series sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(kn)}{n}=\frac{\pi-k}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

According to Wikipedia: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(kn)}{n}=\frac{\pi-k}{2}, 0<k<2\pi$$
How do I prove this? What if $k \ge 2\pi$?

Comment: Look up Fourier series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the function $\;f(x):=\cfrac{\pi-x}2\;$ on $\;[0,\pi]\;$ and extend it to an odd *periodic* function on $\;(-\pi,\pi]\;$ , so that in fact the extension is

$$F(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)=\cfrac{\pi-x}2,&x\in[0,\pi)\\{}\\
-f(-x)=-\cfrac{\pi+x}2,&x\in(-\pi,0)\end{cases}\;\;\;\;,\;\;\;F(x+2\pi)=F(x)\;$$

We can thus write the Fourier series of $\;F\;$ which will only contain sines as $\;F\;$ is an odd function, so $\;a_n=0\;$ for all $\;n=0,1,2,...\;$ , and:

$$b_n=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi F(x)\sin nx\,dx=\frac2\pi\int_0^\pi \frac{\pi-x}2\sin nx\,dx=\int_0^\pi\sin nx\,dx-\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi x\sin nx\,dx=$$

$$=\left.-\frac1n\cos nx\right|_0^\pi+\left.\frac{x\cos nx}\pi\right|_0^\pi+\frac\pi x\int_0^\pi\cos nx\,dx=-\frac{(-1)^n}n+\frac1n+\frac{(-1)^n}n=\frac1n\implies$$

$$\frac{F(x^+)+F(x^-)}2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx}n$$

By Dirichlet's Theorem since $\;F\;$ is piecewise smooth (=continuously differentiable)

Thus,at any continuity point in $\;[-\pi,\pi)\;$, namely: at any $\;x\;$ in this interval different from zero, we have

$$\frac{\pi-x}2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx}n\;,\;\;\text{with periodicity}\;\;2\pi$$

For example, evaluate the above for $\;x=\cfrac\pi2\;$ and get a rather important and very nice infinite sum.

Comment: What if x > 2pi?

Comment: @AndrewFount It is written there: then $\;F(x)=F(x+2\pi)\;$\

Comment: @DonAntonio That is hidden on mobile unless you think to scroll through, which is normally not necessary. It all lines up perfectly in the worst way.

Comment: @gen-ℤreadytoperish I cannot be responsible for people preferring to read this stuff in mobiles and not in big screens in computers. In fact, I cannot understand why would *anyone*  even enter this site from a mobile.

Comment: @DonAntonio That was so aggressive I actually laughed out loud. Why are you being so defensive? It’s just an unfortunate coincidence. As for me, I’m on my phone way more than my laptop, and I browse through here when I’m bored. Then again, I suppose if someone with 194k rep ‘cannot understand why,’ then it must be a ridiculous thing to do 

Answer (score 2):

Proceed as follows,

\begin{align} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(kn)}{n}
&=\frac1{2i}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ikn}-e^{-ikn}}{n}\\
&=\frac1{2i}[-\ln(1-e^{ik})+\ln (1-e^{-ik})]\\
& =\frac1{2i}\ln \frac{1-e^{-ik}}{1-e^{ik}} 
=\frac1{2i}\ln e^{i (\pi-k)}
=\frac{\pi-k}{2}\\
\end{align}

For $k>2\pi$, let $k’= k-2\pi[\frac k{2\pi}]\in (0,2\pi)$. Then,

\begin{align} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(kn)}{n}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(k’n)}{n}
=\frac{\pi-k’}{2}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{kn} \over n} =
{\pi - k \over 2},\quad 0 < k < 2\pi}:\ {\Large ?}}$

---

Note that $\ds{2\pi\!\mid\! k \implies \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{kn} \over n} = 0}$. Hereafter, I'll consider the case
$\ds{2\pi\!\not\mid\! k}$.

---

With $\ds{2\pi\!\not\mid\! k}$ and
$\ds{\hat{k} \equiv \braces{\verts{k} \over 2\pi}2\pi > 0}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{%
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{kn} \over n}} =
k\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{\verts{k}n} \over \verts{k}n} =
k\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{\hat{k}n} \over \verts{k}n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\hat{k}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\mrm{sinc}\pars{\hat{k}n} =
-\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\hat{k} + \mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\hat{k}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\mrm{sinc}\pars{\hat{k}n}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\hat{k}
\\[2mm] &\ + \mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\hat{k}
\bracks{\int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{sinc}\pars{\hat{k}n}\dd n
 + \left.{1 \over 2}\,\mrm{sinc}\pars{\hat{k}x}
\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 0}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\hat{k} + \mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\hat{k}
\pars{{1 \over \hat{k}}\,{\pi \over 2} + {1 \over 2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\hat{k} + \mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\,{\pi \over 2}
\\[5mm] = &
\bbx{\mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\,{\pi - \hat{k} \over 2},\qquad
2\pi \not\mid k,\quad
\hat{k} \equiv \braces{\verts{k} \over 2\pi}2\pi}
\\ &
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\mbox{In general,}
\\ &
\left.\vphantom{A^{A}}
\mrm{f}\pars{k}\right\vert_{\ k\ \in\ \mathbb{R}} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{kn} \over n} =
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{-\mrm{f}\pars{-k}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{k < 0}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{\braces{k \over 2\pi}2\pi}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{k > 2\pi}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\pi - k \over 2} & \mbox{if} & \ds{0 < k < 2\pi}
\\[2mm]
\ds{0} && \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

---

In (\ref{1}), I used the
[Abel-Plana Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula). Note that
\begin{align}
\left.{\sin\pars{\hat{k}\bracks{x + y\ic}} \over \hat{k}\pars{x + y\ic}}\,
\expo{-2\pi\verts{y}}\,\right\vert_{\ x,y\ \in\ \mathbb{R}}
& \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \verts{y}\ \to\ \infty}{\large\sim}\,\,\, 
-\,{\exp\pars{-\bracks{2\pi - \hat{k}}\verts{y}} \over 2\hat{k}\verts{y}}
\\[2mm]
& \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \verts{y}\ \to\ \infty}{\large\to}\,\,\,{\large\color{red}{0}}\ \mbox{whenever}\ \hat{k} < 2\pi
\end{align}
which [$\ds{\underline{\mbox{is required}}}$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.E2) by the above mentioned
*Abel-Plana Formula*.